# Installing buffalo with GO111MODULE results in go get: error loading module requirements

Tags: go, buffalo

I am getting an error when trying to install buffalo.

I tested with a clean GOPATH with nothing in it on `go version go1.12.7 linux/amd64`. `GO111MODULE` ist set to `on`.

I try to install buffalo with the command given on the website:

```
go get -u -v github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo/buffalo
```

Executing the command results in return code `1` and the error message on the end of the verbose output seems to be `go get: error loading module requirements`.

Comment: Try without `-u` flag. The above link has the soln you are seeking i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without the `-u`. This works for me:

```
$ cd $(mktemp -d)
$ go mod init example.com/tempmod
$ go get github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo/buffalo
```

Do those steps work for you?

Some more on `-u` from the [modules wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-upgrade-and-downgrade-dependencies):

> A common mistake is thinking `go get -u foo` solely gets the latest version of foo. In actuality, the `-u` in `go get -u foo` or `go get -u foo@latest` means to *also* get the latest versions for *all* of the direct and indirect dependencies of foo. A common starting point when upgrading foo is instead to do `go get foo` or `go get foo@latest` without a `-u` (and after things are working, consider `go get -u=patch foo`, `go get -u=patch`, `go get -u foo`, or `go get -u`).

Also, with your original command, you were very likely seeing a more specific error earlier in the output. If you run without `-v` to reduce the noise and then ignore the "finding", "downloading", and "extracting" messages, there is probably a more specific error there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. These steps work very well. I read the wiki and ran some tests and I think I understand all of this better now. I was under the impression that go get needs -u to update anything and otherwise only fetches what isn't installed yet. I ran some further tests installing and upating buffalo with and without -v but sadly there is no specific error message other than the one I posted in the question.